# how to detect which level on the dom is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following selector

$('#navigation ul li a').click(function(evt) {}

this get the elements i need, but also retries child elements.

ie i get me this as well

```
#navigation ul li li a  // extra li
```

Just wondering the best way to detect what level of the dom i am selecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **>** which is a `parent > child` selector ..

look at [Child Selector (“parent > child”)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

you could use it something like this

```
$('#navigation>ul>li>a')
```